# Permission Denied when load Firefox Extension in WebDriver

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I'm creating a python script with selenium webdriver. I need to use an extension in firefox, but when I test with a little script, the script produces an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Bot\Mania.py", line 8, in <module>
    firefoxProfile.add_extension(elem)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 93, in add_extension
    self._install_extension(extension)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 264, in _install_extension
    with open(os.path.join(tmpdir, name), 'wb') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpzq3rmztk.firebug-2.0.11-fx.xpi\\content/firebug/'
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

The sample code is it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
import os

firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()
elem = "quickjava-2.0.6-fx.xpi"
firefoxProfile.add_extension(elem)
firefoxProfile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.CSS", 2)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxProfile)
driver.get('http://www.google.cl')
```

PS: The add-on is in the same folder that the script. I tested with full path but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an absolute path to the extension:

```
firefoxProfile.add_extension("/absolute/path/to/the/extension")
```